# Swift Bridge and Closure Band SDK

Tags: swift, swift2, microsoft-band

I'm getting this error when trying to compile this code. Can someone help me debug?:

> Cannot convert value of type '(NSError!) throws -> Void' to expected
>   argument type '((NSError!) -> Void)!'

Header:

```
@class MSBTile;

@protocol MSBTileManagerProtocol <NSObject>

- (void)addTile:(MSBTile *)tile completionHandler:(void(^)(NSError *error))completionHandler;

@end
```

ViewController:

```
client.tileManager.addTile(tile, completionHandler: {
            (error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if error == nil || MSBErrorType(rawValue: error.code) == MSBErrorType.TileAlreadyExist {
                self.output("Creating page...")

                ...
                })
            } else {
                self.output(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        })
```

Comment: "I'm getting this error when trying to run this code" I don't think so. I think you're getting the error when trying to _compile_ the code. It never even starts to run.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I've edited my statement.

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: Xcode 7.2, iOS SDK 9.2, Swift 2.1

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for anyone who encounters this in the future. It turns out that two of the function calls were also throwables, so I had to wrap them in try catch blocks like so:

```
 let pageTextBlock: AnyObject
                    do {
                        pageTextBlock = try MSBPageTextBlockData(elementId: 10, text: "TextButton Sample")
                    }catch _ {
                        pageTextBlock = ""
                    }

                    let pageButtonBlock: AnyObject
                    do {
                        pageButtonBlock = try MSBPageTextButtonData(elementId: 11, text: "Press Me")
                    }catch _ {
                        pageButtonBlock = ""
                    }
```

Disclaimer: I'm still new to Swift so this may not be the best solution.